# ffmpeg development recompile only changed part on windows

Tags: c, windows, ffmpeg, linker, mingw-w64

New to ffmpeg development, i am trying to develop a patch for a specific demuxer in avformat and sure i want to be able to test my changes without recompiling all parts of ffmpeg again as it takes about an hour. My toolchain is set up as per https://ffmpeg.org/platform.html 4.1.1. Using mingw64.exe, it was no problem to compile an initial version:

```
./configure --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl
make -j4
```

Voila, i have a shared build, means the .exe and .dll files are built and i can run the program successfully.

Now when i change some code , e.g. in libavformat/pcm.c, i can recompile this part easily by doing

```
make pcm.o
```

make will even recognize automatically if there were changes to the code and only rebuild the single .o file. But when executing make in the root path of the ffmpeg source again, it will always recompile all .o files which of course something i want to avoid.

I tried disabling some components e.g. by doing

```
./configure --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-avisynth --enable-gpl --disable-avcodec --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter
```

But this way, i am only getting a new avutil.dll, avscale.dll and avresample.dll but no avformat.dll (which i dont understand because i dont disable avformat), also it seems to recompile the parts instead of re-using and just link the existing .o files together.

How could i tell the make command not to compile anything but instead just link all the existing .o files - and only for avformat instead of all parts?

Comment: As long as you don't rerun configure or make clean between builds, only changed files will be rebuilt.

Comment: Thats the answer, just running make after a change only takes a few seconds and only rebuilds the stuff that it needs to rebuild. Thank you so much grandmaster Gyan! ..you know i wonder since a long time why you typically just comment everything instead of posting an answer?

Comment: Because often the Q omits important info or the real question is something different. So, when I make a semi-informed guess, it is in the comments.

Comment: Yeah i see, my question was too easy to be real :D thanks a bunch!